# C++: find(str,ind) returns several -1

Tags: c++, string, find

As an example, if I enter "love" as the string and search for character "o," I get:

- Found 1 and Position: 0
- Found 1 and Position: 1
- Found -1 and Position 2
- The character's last position: -1 and index is: 3

As another example, if I enter: "I love you" and search for character "v," I get:

- Found: 4 and Position: 0
- Found: 4 and Position: 1
- Found: 4 and Position: 2
- Found: 4 and Position: 3
- Found: 4 and Position: 4
- Found: -1 and Position: 5
- Found: -1 and Position: 6
- Found: -1 and Position: 7
- Found: -1 and Position: 8

.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    char ch;
    int i, found;

    cout << "Please input a string: ";
    getline (cin, str);

    cout << "Please input a character: ";
    cin.get(ch);

    cout << "The string is: " << str << " and the character is: " << ch << endl;
    cout << "The string length is: " << str.length() << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++)
    {

        found = str.find(ch, i);
        cout << "Found: " << found << " and Position: " << i << endl;

        if (i == str.length())
        {
            i = found + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "The character's last position: " << found << " and the index is: " << i << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, but the "-1"(s) are causing me a problem. I would just like the position that the character was found as I iterate through the string looking for the character. Any help will be appreciated.

I am teaching myself C++ and this is a problem in the book. I am supposed to use found. The problem statement:

(Program) Write a C++ program that accepts both a string and a single character from the user. The program should determine how many times the character is contained in the string. (Hint: Search the string by using the find(str, ind) function. This function should be used in a loop that starts the index value at 0 and then changes the index value to 1 past the index of where the char was last found.)

References:

[1] Bronson, Gary J.. C++ for Engineers and Scientists (Page 543). Cengage Textbook. Kindle Edition.

Comment: That function returns `std::string::npos` (which has the value -1 converted to unsigned) when it fails. Check for that value and exit the loop: there are no more matches.

Comment: I am supposed to use "find(str,ind)", rather.

Comment: So it returns -1 when it fails. That is odd because I can input: "I love you", serach for 'o', and get no -1 even though u is after o.

Comment: thlt is because you loop until `i < str.length() - 1`. So you are not seraching from the second 'o' onwards in 'i love you'

Comment: Actually, I forgot that I changed it to str.length() - 1. Without str.length()-1 (str.length()), I get a -1 at the end. 

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [c++ reference on string::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) you are using variant (4) which reads

```
size_t find (char c, size_t pos = 0) const;
```

where the parameters are explained as

```
pos
   Position of the first character in the string to be considered in the search.
   If this is greater than the string length, the function never finds matches.
   Note: The first character is denoted by a value of 0 (not 1): A 
   value of 0 means that the entire string is searched.
```

and

```
c
   Individual character to be searched for.
```

under return value we find

```
The position of the first character of the first match.
If no matches were found, the function returns string::npos.
```

Let's go through some example, let's take `love` as it is shorter and we look at `string("love").find('o', i)` where `i` ranges from `0` to `2 < string("love").length() - 1 = 3`

i = 0

```
love
^ first considered char
 ^ reported find so return value is 1
```

i = 1

```
love
 ^ first considered char
 ^ reported find so return value is 1
```

i = 2

```
love
  ^first considered char
  -- no match after that position, so return value is string::npos (== -1 most implementations)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong:

[std::basic_string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) return position of the first character of the found substring **or [npos](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) if no such substring is found**.

```
static const size_type npos = -1;
```